# Why CSS Media Queries look different even though screens have the same resolution

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, responsive, elementor

I have created a Wordpress website using Elementor live builder and some jQuery and CSS mainly. Here's the CSS:

```
#menu-contact, #menu-solutions, #menu-about, #menu-regulation, #menuu { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #0B1B70; 
justify-content: center;
display: inline-block;
min-width: 60px;
max-width: 235.97px;
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
} 

.menu-item-text {
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-o-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid transparent; 
border-top: 2.11px solid transparent; 
}


#menuu:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menuu:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menuu:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}
#menu-contact:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-contact:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-contact:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#menu-solutions:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-solutions:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-solutions:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#menu-about:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-about:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-about:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#menu-regulation:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-regulation:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-regulation:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}


@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-contact {

    }
}
    @media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-solutions {
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-regulation {
      left: 30px;
}
}

    @media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-about {
      left: 88px;
    }
    }
       @media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menuu {
          left: 40px

    }
       }

@media (max-width: 1279px) {
  #menu-contact {
      right: 66px;
    }
}
    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-solutions {
padding (0, 20px, 0, 0)
  }
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-regulation {
margin-left: 65px;
}
}

    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-about {
margin-left: 45px;
    }
    }
       @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menuu {
right: ;       }

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-contact {
      right: 66px;
    }
}
    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-solutions {
padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-regulation {
margin-left: 65px;
}
}

    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-about {
margin-left: 45px;
    }
    }
       @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menuu {
margin-left: 0px;
    }
       }

              @media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menu-contact {
margin-left: 42px;    }
}
    @media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menu-solutions {
left: 14px;    }
}
@media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menu-regulation {
right: 60px;}

}


    @media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menu-about {
            left: 12px
      }
    }
       @media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menuu {
padding: 0px 26px 0px 0px;
    }
       }

       @media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-contact {
margin-left: 52px;    }
}
    @media (max-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-solutions {
left: 14px;    }
}
@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-regulation {
right: 78px;}

}


    @media (max-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-about {
padding: 0px  105px 0px 0px;
    }
    }
       @media (max-width: 1920px) {
  #menuu {
padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    }
       }
```

I have styled the main menu at the top according to several desktop screens I have- 1920, 1680 and 1280 width. I needed to use padding, left, right and margins because I noticed some attributes didn't always work. But the main issue is that when I check the menu on my laptop, which has the 1920px width too but is 15" and not 25", the gaps between the menu links aren't equal and they change.

Here's the link: [mayabarber.co.il](http://mayabarber.co.il)

I can't attach HTML because it was created with a live builder and I didn't write it.

Since media queries are related to screen resolution, what can I do when it comes to same resolution screens with different styling? How can I make it look well on 1920 width screen, both on 15" and 21"+.

Thanks!

Comment: Do both of your screens have the same zoom level? e.g. on Windows the value 100%, 125% in the screen settings? You could also check the number of actually rendered pixels by opening the DevTools and selecting the `<body>` tag. Then you should see the rendered pixel width of the page. btw. you don't need a single media query for every css statement, you can combine multiple statements into one media query.

Comment: Same zoom size and same browser. Checked several laptops (14"-15") and the items look different. How can numbers help me if the gaps are different? On my main 25" screen they look pretty much equal. But on the laptop f.e #menu-about looks too close to #menuu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your head tag

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I would never `user-scalable=no`, as it breaks usability.

Comment: @ThomasScheffer so what should I do then? I want all 1920 width resolution screens look similar no matter what my screen size is.

Comment: @RoziBuber `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` should be enough. Also have a look at your css, as all the media query rules are applied to the previous widths aswell. You never use the (min-width) in a query

Comment: I added this code, was anything supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify a general screen size range,then distinguishing between retina and non-retina screens.
For Example,

```
/* ----------- Non-Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
              and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
              and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
 }

 /* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
 @media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
               and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
               and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
               and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
 }
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I see how it can make the CSS way shorter and it's reasonable, however I'm still trying to figure out why 1920px screen width style looks different on my 15" laptop and 25" desktop screen. :)